# WPF: DependencyProperty works on TextBlock but not on custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

**Edit:** a sample project can be found [here](http://zoy.org/~sam/WpfApp1.zip).

I am using a `ListBox` inside my main window, which I later bind to an `ObservableCollection`. I use both a `TextBlock` and a custom control which I bind to the same property of the collection. My problem is that the `TextBlock` gets properly updated, whereas the custom control doesn’t (it gets default constructed but its `Text` property is never updated by the binding).

```
<ListBox Name="MyCustomItemList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
                <local:MyCustomBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I implemented `MyCustomBlock` as a child of `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` with a `Text` dependency property:

```
public class MyCustomBlock : Canvas
{
    public MyCustomBlock() => Text = "<default>";
    public MyCustomBlock(string text) => Text = text;

    private static void TextChangedCallback(DependencyObject o,
                                            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
              nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomBlock),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", TextChangedCallback));
}
```

Finally, this is the data I bind to the `ListBox` in the `MainWindow` constructor:

```
public class MyCustomItem
{
    public MyCustomItem(string text) => ItemText = text;
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var list = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomItem>();
    list.Add(new MyCustomItem("Hello"));
    list.Add(new MyCustomItem("World"));
    MyCustomItemList.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Did I forget something in my setup? How come `TextBlock.Text` is seemingly properly updated but not `MyCustomBlock.Text`?

Comment: how did you verified that property in custom control is never updated by the binding?

Comment: So you've put a breakpoint in TextChangedCallback and it's never hit?

Comment: Yes, I added a breakpoint in `TextChangedCallback` and it is called when the `MyCustomBlock` is default-constructed (so, `Text` is set to `"<default>"`) but it is never called after that.

Comment: What if you don't set the Text property in the constructors? Doing so seems redundant anyway. You could as well use `"<default>"` as default property value in the property metadata. And just to be sure, you don't explicitly set the control's DataContext somewhere?

Comment: The value set in the constructor has "local" [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) and overrides anything set by the template that created the control instance.

Comment: Have you tried manually forcing 2-way binding? `<local:MyCustomBlock Text="{Binding ItemText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`.

Comment: @BrianReichle Thanks! Can you maybe write a short answer from this comment? Several solutions here work, but that one is the real reason the code does not work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency properties can get their value from several sources and so WPF employs a [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) system to determine which value applies. "Local" values (provided using [SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473(v=vs.110).aspx) or [SetBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding(v=vs.110).aspx)) will override anything provided by the creating template.

In your case, your setting a "local" value in the constructor (presumably intending it to behave as a default value). A better way to set a default value is by providing it in the PropertyMetadata.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
          nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomBlock),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("<default>", TextChangedCallback));
```